# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Test_speak' At terminal

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I need to run python script from terminal. The script work perfect in Pycharm but whenever I try to import the module I created in terminal it shows above error.

I tried to add the entire directory in PYTHONPATH:

PYTHONPATH=$HOME/home/shyna/PycharmProjects/Shyna623
also PYTHONPATH=home/shyna/PycharmProjects/Shyna623

Some other thread suggested to have empty init file,Pycharm creats it automatically still I double checked that too.

I navigate to that specific directory and tried to run code still same error.

I tried to do sudo Python3 and then tried to import the same module, still error. I did python3 (without sudo) and still same error.

Python file also have #! /usr/bin/python3

I'm not using any virtaul enviroment to run script.

Directory is like:
home
./shivam
./Pycharmproject
./Shyna623
Shyna_speak.py (Module which have main and test user defined functions)

[image]

[image]

Comment: make sure pycharm and your system are using the same interpreter - pycharm may be using a virtualenv

Comment: Yes, I checked. I don't have virtaulenv configured.

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of the directory structure in Pycharm, the imports that are failing as code and the error message you are getting?

Comment: I have added images for both